# Refreshing ListBox outside an update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

In my application, I have a list box(list of stores), Add and Remove buttons and another list box (selected stores).

I have Following requirements:
1. On click of Add button, copy selected items from the master stores list to the selected store list and clear the selection from master store list.
2. On Click of Remove button, remove the selected stores from the selected stores list.

I have added my master store list box and selected store list boxes to 2 different update panels and added triggers for each of the update panel. Things are working fine but one thing I have observed that it is taking unusually long to move selected stores from master list to selected list. I have around 5000 entries in the master list of stores.

If I remove the update panel for master store list, things are normal but I am not able to clear the selection. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to clear selection of listbox outside the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your using UpdatePanels to move ListItems between 2 ListBox controls.  This creates a overhead as each time you trigger the 'add' event it has to postback and render the UpdatePanel again (including the viewstate).

Have you looked into using jQuery to move your list items between your ListBox controls thus all the moving between boxes is handled by the browser.  This will speed up the experience for the user?

You should also be able to use jQuery to clear the selection.  If you can provide me a little snippet of your markup I can help you get it written up (or shoot me a message).

Brian =)